# Printing lines in which atleast one assignment operator(=) even if a conditional operator(==) exits in that line

Tags: bash, unix, awk, sed, grep

In ***unix scripting***

I have a file which has lines as follows:

```
if(a==b || b=c && c==d)
if(a!=b)
if(a=b)
```

i have to print only those lines which is having assignment operator i.e

```
if(a==b || b=c && c==d) and
if(a=b)
```

Anybody pls Help

---

Comment: Your question is vague, please explain more.

Comment: What if `a=b` only exists in a comment or in a string?

Comment: Crossposting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/387259/74329

Comment: Crossposting: https://askubuntu.com/q/947997/336375

Answer (score 1):

So what you're looking for is (simplistically) an `=` on its own, with no other `=` abutting it. This can be done with the regex `[^=]=[^=]` (an `=` with something *other* than `=` on both sides).

Unfortunately, that will also capture things like `!=` or `>=` so you may want to expand it a bit. As a start:

```
grep '[^!<>=]=[^=]' inputFile
```

That should catch the vast majority although you're in the same boat as those who want to process XML with regexes rather than an XML processor - there will probably always be some edge case that you don't get simply because regex is a far simpler tool than a language parser. However, as stated, it should be fine for all but the weirdest of edge cases.

And you may still have to handle cases where (for example) the `=` may be at the start or end of the line but this would be pretty unlikely since any coder formatting their code like that is clearly insane :-)

Comment: but that pattern will print `if(a!=b)` line too

Comment: Good point, @tso, have updated to cater to those (and, of course, to state there may be others).

Comment: if(a!=b || a=b)
how to grep this? since this also has an assignment operator

Comment: @AyushMalik, it will be picked up because the second `=` has something other than `!<>=` before it and something other then `=` after it. The `grep` doesn't *exclude* lines with (for example) `!=`, it *ignores* that in terms of detecting an assignment. Hence the presence of the assignment still selects the line.

Answer (score 0):

The following should be a decent approximation with GNU grep:

```
grep -E '([[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]]|^)=([[:alnum:]]|[[:space:]]|$)'
```

This will show `=` delimited by alpha-numeric and whitespaces. It won't find `=` delimited by punctuation (e.g `(=)`) - we can't just add `[[:punct:]]` to the character classes (or just replace them with `[[:print:]]`) because that would include `==` and `!=`. It's possible to manually specify punctuation apart from `=` and `!` if you want.